# ObjC / iOS: How to retrieve unicode hex code for character?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring

So, I know how to convert a unicode hex code into an NSString consisting of the unicode character referenced by that code:

```
NSString *ucStr = @"\\u004A"; // hex code for capital J
NSString *theLetter = [ucStr mutableCopy];
CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)theLetter, NULL, transform, YES);
// theLetter is now @"J"
```

...However, I don't seem to understand how to go in the other direction, i.e. starting with an NSString `@"J"`, output the NSString `@"004A"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply extract each character and format it using the format string `@"%04x"`, as below:

```
NSString *input = @"How now brown cow";
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [input length]; i++) {
    unichar c = [input characterAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%04x", (unsigned)c);
    // or NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04x", (unsigned)c];
}
```

BTW I don't understand the code you have posted, but as that wasn't the question, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks!  Frankly I don't understand the code I posted either, it was given to me on StackOverflow some weeks ago :)  If you know of a less obtuse way to accomplish the same thing, though, would love to hear that as well... (will accept your answer as soon as it lets me)

Comment: @CyberMew Why is that?  Don't they fit within the 16-bits of UTF-16?

Comment: why a cast to (unsigned)? `unichar` is already an unsigned short.

Comment: Because the `%x` modifier expects an `unsigned`, not `unsigned short`.